# Goto possibly causing a race condition when parsing excel data

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to parse a bunch of data that I've pulled from putty log files.  Ive imported the data into excel and now I'm trying to cleanup the data to the point where I can compare the actual network state with the desired network state.  If i step through the code it works properly,  but when i run it, it seems locks up excel with no error code.

Ive tried removing all the logic from this macro, and the issue seems to be caused by my Goto statement.  THe code will run without issues without that goto statement.

```
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
PageBreakState = ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim currentrow As Integer
Dim val As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


currentrow = 2
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


Do Until currentrow >= lastrow
startloop:
val = Range("A" & currentrow).Value

If val = "" Then
    Rows(currentrow).Delete
    GoTo startloop
End If

If val Like "*[/]#[/]*" Then

Else
    Rows(currentrow).Delete
    GoTo startloop
End If
currentrow = currentrow + 1

Loop


Columns("B:I").EntireColumn.Delete

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
currentrow = 1
nextloop:
Do Until currentrow >= lastrow
If Range("B" & currentrow).Value = "" Then
    Range("c" & currentrow & ":M" & currentrow).Copy Range("b" & currentrow)
End If
currentrow = currentrow + 1
Loop



Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = PageBreakState
```

Comment: Don't use `GoTo`. That creates spaghetti code. Let your `If` statements control logic flow.

Comment: Also, don't use `Integer`. Use `Long`. And delete rows from the bottom up. Easily accomplished by replacing your `Do` loop with a `For...Next` loop with `Step -1`.

Comment: thanks for taking the time BigBen.  Im still very new at this and trying to self learn.  If i understand the for..next statement, i should have something along the lines of for currentrow = lastrow to 2 step -1....next

Comment: Yes that looks right.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Obviously had to remove my manual counter, and goto loops. but really happy with this.  Thanks again BigBen

Comment: Great! Glad to help. Happy coding.